# Please let me know how the phrase ''it being'' is rational?

Tags: syntax

I've read an article on the BBC news, and this sentence really makes me confused.

''*And in this cool little video Aston has just released, you can see **it very much being pushed to its limits** by a real driver*''

I know how it would be translated into my native language, but to be honest I cannot find out what grammar tense or structure that the highlighted portion belongs to.

Does it mean ''it is being pushed to its limits''?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means:

> A real driver is pushing it to its limits, and you can see this.

The thing that you can see — the “this”, if you would — is the real driver pushing it to its limits.

The object of the verb *see*  is here the entire gerund clause following it. It’s a gerund clause whose subject is the object pronoun *it*.

Sense verbs do this: they can take either a gerund or an infinitive.  Since neither is a tensed verb form, a pronoun serving as the subject of a gerund or infinitive clause needs to be in the object case not the subject case.

- I watched **them playing** in the park.
- I heard **him calling** for help.
- They observed **me struggling** to find purchase.
- We smelled **them flowering** at their peak.
- You noticed **him coming in** without wiping his shoes first.
- The winter wind was awful; I felt **it leaking** through the cracked window frame.

Using the gerund instead of the infinitive gives it a continuous sense that does not apply to the corresponding infinitive clause:

- I watched **them play** in the park.
- I heard **him call** for help.
- They observed **me struggle** to find purchase.
- We smelled them flower at their peak.
- You noticed **him come** in without wiping his shoes first.
- The winter wind was awful; I felt **it leak** through the cracked window frame.

Comment: Because I didn't really bother looking at the preceding clause, I initially interpreted it as a variant on *I can see this question being closed*. I don't know which if any other verbs besides ***see*** (and perhaps ***imagine***) allow ***being*** to be used with an unstated *I can see this question being closed **in the [near] future***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersI can imagine it being/getting used that way. I could envision it being/getting used that way.

Comment: I can imagine you being a formidable opponent in a debate. But in *that* usage it's pragmatically perfectly feasible to suppose that what I might think I'm imagining primarily relates to your *past/present* actions, not "future".

Comment: Thank you @tchrist. Your very thorough and detailed explanation of gerund cleared up my confusing. Thus I know the problem is that I didn't consider the entire sentence after the comma it (the highlighted words) concerns but just a individual words. Yet could you please tell me more about using gerund in contexts? Are there any other situations that I might see a gerund?

Comment: @LuongVu Using a gerund phrase is easy: it can go anywhere that a noun can go, including as the subject of a sentence (like this one).